# Breaking from function not loop in R

Tags: r, break

Ok so I am writing a larger function that call a few functions.

The issue is that I need to break out of "function_inner" under certain logical conditions without breaking out of "function_outer".  Break seems to work for loops, and stop, well it stops all functions... any ideas?

```
function_outer <- function(){

    beta =1
        function_inner <- function(beta){
        if (beta==1){?break?stop}
        print("Its not working")
         }
    return(beta)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean to `return` a value?

```
function_outer <- function(){

  beta =1
  function_inner <- function(beta){
    if (beta==1){ return("Inner beta is 1") }
    print("Its not working")
     }
  return(beta)
}
```

Comment: No, I just need to stop running function_inner... however I guess I could just return something from it.  That might work.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, returning a value should exit out of the function in the way you intended, even if you don't need that value.

Comment: Thanks. I was using a plain return, but when I returned a value, it stopped executing. Your explanation helped.

Comment: Looking back on this, `return(NULL)` would be a pretty good idiom for this.

Comment: However, you still might want to break out of a function in an `*apply` or `replicate` call, if you don't know in advance how many times the function should be run.  In my case I am trying to make a function to read a large file whose length is unknown at the start.  `replicate` is by far the quickest way to read in the information, but runs a pre-specified number of times.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: @bazz Probably needs its own question, but my initial thought is that breaking out of `*apply`-style commands (including `replicate`) is not very R-like.  It's unlikely that `replicate` is much faster to run than a loop.  Just use `while` or `repeat`, as this use case is what they were designed for.

Comment: @Ari Thanks.  I did actually ask this question.  I was given a couple of ideas, but most people said that loops weren't that bad really, as you have.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220552/exit-a-function-within-apply