# Exit a function within *apply

Tags: r, function, apply, exit

`sapply` and `replicate` (etc.) run a specified number of times.  Putting `sapply(1:N, function(n){expr})` will execute `expr` N times.  Supposing I wanted `sapply` to stop after m runs.  Is this possible without making an error?  `break` doesn't work, and a `for` or `while` loop would be too slow in my context.

Something akin to:

```
sapply(1:N, function(n){
  #some expression
  if(identical(n, m)) break
})
```

except that break doesn't work.

What I'm trying to do:

Creating a function to read in large (binary) data files of a defined structure but unknown lengths.  Using `replicate` with `array(readBin(...), ...)` is the best way I've found to do this, but I'd like it to stop when `NA` starts to be returned (i.e. end of file is reached).

Comment: As far as I know, `for` loops are supported in R and _can_ be used, despite the bad reputation. Thinking that a `sapply` is faster than a `for` loop is a common misconception.

Comment: My experience is that `for` is much slower than the `apply` family and I have tried doing this task with `for` (before I really knew about `*apply`).  Are there some tips for making `for` work faster?

Comment: `for` is not _much_ slower than `*apply` by any means. It's generally (a little) slower than `lapply` and `vapply`. Depending on the situation, can be slower or faster than `sapply`. It's generally _faster_ than `apply`. This provided that you write correctly the loop and (more than other things) avoid growing objects and preallocate correctly. Be more detailed about your attempt and you may have help.

Comment: @nicola `for` itself should actually be faster than other loops (including `vapply`). What you do inside it can make it slower.

Comment: @Roland What you say is right if you exclude the time of the allocation before the loop. If you try `allocate(res);fillResWithForLoopCallingFun(input)` and compare with `vapply(input,Fun,returnValue)` I still have to find a case in which `for` wins. If you just wrap `Fun` in a loop without worrying about storing the result, `for` wins, but I don't think it's a fair comparison.

Comment: @nicola True, but you can use a `for` loop without a return value and that's where it wins. That's what I mean, the loop itself is fast.

Comment: Well, maybe I'm not using loops well, but `replicate` definitely beat `repeat` here.  See comment on R.S.'s answer below.

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting downvoted!  The answer was that you shouldn't try doing this, but the alternative is actually fine.  Doesn't make it a bad question.  It prompted good discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial workaround can be to used in form of global control variable

```
i<-TRUE
unlist( sapply(1:10, function(x){if(i){ if(x>=4)(i<<-FALSE); 2*x;}}) )
```

Though it still runs n times, at least it does not perform the operation every time and spares resources. 
And I can't exactly make out why simplification did not work all the way and I had to use unlist.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good idea.  I think that it doesn't simplify within `sapply` because it wants to retain the `NULL` values.

Comment: Tried this and it is much quicker than using a `for`/ `while`/ `repeat` loop.  0.25 s compared to 4.8 s.  Will make a big difference when I feed in larger files.  I remain to be convinced that `for` can compete with `*apply`.

Comment: Happy to be of some help.

Comment: @Bazz You are obviously making a serious mistake when writing `for` loops in R. My bet would be on growing objects (which can be avoided easily enough).

Comment: Or when others have to make sense of your code at some time. A for loop is easier to debug too, IMHO.

Comment: I should think that I do have growing objects, but given the nature of what I am trying to do (read in a large file), it's hard to see how I would avoid that.  My script reads in an array at a time and then binds it.  I suppose each call of `abind` has to evaluate the large array.  Would you feed each result into a list entry and then do `do.call(abind, c(lst, along = N))` afterwards?

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  When I do that the `repeat` loop takes 0.36 s.  Both methods seem to be seizing up when they try to bind the arrays together at the end though.

Comment: I've added my findings in an answer below - does that seem right?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the `for` vs `*apply` battle, if your problem is to use `readBin` until the end of file is reached, keep in mind that:

- you can use a (small) overestimate for `n` (the number of elements to read);
- you can know the size of the file through `file.info(filename)$size`; then you can estimate by yourself how many elements are contained in the file.

For instance, say that you are reading integer (four bytes) values. Just try:

```
readBin(con,"int",n=file.info(filename)$size/4+10)
```

to read all the file in one shot. The `+10` is to make a little overestimation.

Comment: Thanks.  This is helpful.  An additional complication though is that there are 16-byte strings within the file as well which say what each array represents and 4-byte integers within the file as well as metadata.  There are two integers (4), one string (16), three integers (4) giving the dimensions of the array, and then an array of doubles, repeating an unspecified number of times.  It's true that you can roughly know how many arrays, so I can progress for now.  See http://water.usgs.gov/ogw/modflow/MODFLOW-2005-Guide/ -> FAQ -> L for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd post what I came up with for this.  `cbb` is the array being built.  In the bad example, `cbb` is progressively built up as an array using `abind`.  At each step, `cbb` has to be re-evaluated and so each successive step is slower - a growing object.  In the good example, `cbb` is built up as a list and a new list entry is declared with each step.  R does not need to re-evaluate the existing list each time.  The array is bound together at the end with `do.call(abind, c(cbb, list(along = 4)))`.

One thing I found helpful was to put `cat(".")` within the loop.  If the dot printing slows down, that might indicate a growing object.  With the good example, dots are printed at a more or less constant rate.  The good example is about ten times faster than the bad.

BAD:

```
cbb <- array(NA, c(N1, N2, N3, 0))
repeat{ 
    sptsnew <- readBin(to.read, "integer", 2L, 4L)
    if(identical(sptsnew, integer(0))){cat("\nend of file\n"); break}
    ... #reading array metadata
    cbb <- abind(cbb, array(readBin(to.read, "double", N1*N2*N3, 4L), c(N1, N2, N3, 1)), along = 4)
    cat(".")
}
```

GOOD:

```
i <- 1
cbb <- list()
repeat{ 
    sptsnew <- readBin(to.read, "integer", 2L, 4L)
    if(identical(sptsnew, integer(0))){cat("\nend of file\n"); break}
    ... #reading array metadata
    cbb[[i]] <- array(readBin(to.read, "double", N1*N2*N3, 4L), c(N1, N2, N3, 1))
    i <- i + 1
    cat(".")
}
cbb <- do.call(abind, c(cbb, list(along = 4)))
```